# How get data in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm newbie with Firebase. I try to get data in Database, but my code is not working. Here is my code:

```
- (void) getData{

    FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

    //READ DATA

    [[[ref child:@"buysell"] child:@"users"]  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
}
```

It cant jump in `withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot)`. What seems to be wrong? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: have you configured properly? i mean according to their guidelines.

Comment: I follow document of google.[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this to viewDidLoad
FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

1. Check whether you configured everything according to the documentation.
2. Check the key names
3. If everything is fine then try changing this
   Try with observeSingleEventOfType instead of observeEventType

   ```
   [[[self.ref child:@"buysell"] child:@"users"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",dict);

   } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
   }];
   ```
4. If above 3 not works check your error statement

Comment: Thanks U. It is work! It's jump 2 time in funcition :)

Comment: block is asynchronous so it will not jump inside the block for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily. If you want to fetch all info using this you can do this. Make sure your db is public

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

Define Property on interface then

```
 self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
     [self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

            NSLog(@"Information : %@",usersDict);
        }];
```

If you want to fetch specific portion using this you can do this

```
 [[self.ref child:@"results"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

        NSLog(@"Info : %@",usersDict);



    }];
```

My Fetched Json From Firebase

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      }
 ]
}
```